# AR - Button stays on the screen when off the target

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I have a problem with a button that stays on the screen when off the target.

Additional Info

---

- Canvas Render Mode: World Space
- Tree:

  - ARCamera
  - ImageTarget
  - Canvas

    - Button
    - Text

Platform used: Vuforia and Unity 2017.1.0f2

Comment: There's a setting for this in Vuforia's target options. I forget what it's called.

Comment: Thank you. I will check.

Comment: Draco18s, I checked and there was no settings for that.

Comment: Hmm. I swear there was an option that controlled what happened to the object when the target went out of frame. Its been a while since I've worked with it extensively.

Comment: I think you were referring to extended tracking checkbox. If my assumption is correct, the checkbox was already unchecked.